# Use getComputedStyle to identify the CSS font-weight for all P tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, getcomputedstyle

**Objective**

- To use getComputedStyle to identify the CSS font-weight assigned to
  text in a page and note this as text into a span at the start of the P tag/s.

**Reason**

- To create a bookmarklet for personal use in identifying where CSS is
  used to apply strong/bolded text visually. Then a determination can
  be made if the CSS should be replaced with HTML strong.

**Issues**

- Only applies to first P tag in the page.
- Replaces existing text rather than adding to the existing word/s.

**Code so far**

```
var newClass = document.getElementsByTagName('p')
var length = newClass.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  newClass[i].className =  newClass[i].className + "font--weight"
}

let pAll = document.querySelector('p.font--weight');
let calcStyles = window.getComputedStyle(pAll);
pAll.textContent = 'My computed font-weight is ' + calcStyles.getPropertyValue('font-weight');
pAll.innerHTML = '<span>' + pAll.textContent + '</span>';
```

- Is this possible, if no there ends the question.
- Is there a better way to achieve this?
- Needed in JavaScript not jQuery.

Comment: Can you add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `el.querySelectorAll()` to get the ***nodeList***, `el.querySelector()` will return the first node of the selector only. Then  you just need to use `getComputedStyle(selector).getPropertyValue('style')` to get the computed style. From there is just concatenating the strings together and setting the ***innerHTML*** or ***textContent*** to the string.

Once you have the ***nodeList***, run the elements through a loop to get each one.

```js
let pTagClass = document.querySelectorAll('.check-weight')

function getFontWeight(els) {
  els.forEach(weight => {
    // weight now represents each individual node in 
    // our nodeList that was passed into the function
    let compStyle = getComputedStyle(weight).getPropertyValue('font-weight');
    let str = `<span class="bookmark">font-weight is: ${compStyle},</span>`
    let currentText = weight.textContent
    weight.innerHTML = `${str} ${currentText}`
  })
}

getFontWeight(pTagClass)
```

```css
.check-weight {
  font-family: "Bahnschrift", sans-serif;
}

.heavy {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.normal {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.light {
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.bookmark {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: smaller;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<p class="heavy check-weight">This is a heavy weight</p>
<p class="heavy check-weight">This is also a heavy weight</p>
<p class="light check-weight">This is a light weight</p>
<p class="normal check-weight">This is normal</p>
```